# Does Calling GC.Collect() Do Garbage Collection On Only Your Process or All Processes?

Tags: .net, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, out-of-memory

When you call GC.Collect on a machine, does it do collection for the entire machine/all processes or does it only do collection for the process calling it?

There are only two answers here to choose from:

1. All processes
2. Only calling process

*Please do NOT reply "you should never force garbage collection". There are lot's of posts on that.

For sake of discussion, let's say you inherited the worst app ever made which creates lots of garbage, runs repeat processes, and eventually crashes once a day due to running out of memory. You have no source code to fix it, but it must keep running, because your business depends on it. Could you create a utility app to run every 30 minutes to force garbage collection on the machine to keep that process from running out of memory?

Comment: If it runs out of memory, forcing garbage collection will most likely not change that. GC only cleans reclaimable memory and it should already be doing that in the background without being prodded.

Comment: If the app was written in c#, you can get uncommented source code by running a decompiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only your process. The .Net runtime is instantiated in your own process, so you only control your own .Net internals.

Comment: Besides, the garbage collector runs before running out of memory. If that's your actual problem, forcing a GC won't help at all, what you have is either rooted managed objects, unmanaged objects fragmenting your 32-bit address space, or just unmanaged objects that fill your available memory.

Answer (score 1):

Your process only as mentioned before. I want to add the following and provide a possible solution:

You application is probably leaking memory and GC.Collect will do no good assuming you have the source code. The way around this is to increase your virtual memory to many times what you currently got. You can also write a watchdog application that will automatically relaunch the application when it crashes due to being out of memory.

Assuming you have a lot of virtual memory the leaked memory will be paged out to disk never to be accessed again and will probably have little or no impact on performance and delay the inevitable enough to allow you to intervene and gracefully restart the application.

Comment: Thank you for the idea of increasing virtual memory. It's not optimal, but I had not thought of that. I will try this and see what happens.